# Collecting bonus miles from family flights on the Emirates Skywards program

Tags: loyalty-programs, emirates

So my sister and grandfather are travelling from SFO-DXB and since it is a one off trip for them, I though I could add them to my family bonus program and collect their 20% miles for myself. How do I refer their two tickets back to my skywards account to collect these miles since they don't have any skywards members of their own?

Comment: Even though it might be possible, airlines are likely to frown upon this. What you definitely won't be able to do is to add your frequent flyer number to both.

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee: The Emirates Family Bonus program seems to be specifically designed for families to merge their miles, at least to some extent.  I agree this is unusual as most airlines are strict about only awarding miles to the person who flew.

Comment: @NateEldredge Hmmm looks like there can be interesting answer to this question then. I'm not very familiar with Emirates' FF so perhaps someone who does can answer?

Comment: Emirates specifically allots you FF numbers for your family members that you add in your account. I'm going to visit their office tomorrow. Will update when I get a definitive answer.

Comment: @user3079474 have you had any success finding an answer to this?

Comment: when you add a family member in your skywards account, emirates allotts each family member an FF number. use that FF number and the miles the family members earned are credited to your account. (I'll add pictures if its not clear enough, yet @drat )

Comment: The best would be if you could write an answer for the reference of future users :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add a family member in your skywards account, Emirates allots each family member a FF number. Use that FF number and 20% of the miles the family members earns are credited to your account.

The FF number of the family members is displayed in the family section of your skywards account.